# Database columns not being created from base class

Tags: django, django-models, django-migrations

I am trying to run migrations from a **Django 5.0** project, with the **default SQLite database** connected.

The contents of my **models.py** file are as follows

```
class CustomBaseModel(models.Model):
    InsertedBy = models.BigIntegerField(blank=False),
    InsertedDateTime = models.DateTimeField(blank=False, auto_now_add=True),
    UpdatedBy = models.BigIntegerField(blank=False),
    UpdatedDateTime = models.DateTimeField(blank=False, auto_now_add=True),
    class Meta:
        abstract = True


class ExcelColumnDataType(CustomBaseModel):
    DataTypeName = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=False)
    class Meta(CustomBaseModel.Meta):
        db_table = "ExcelColumnDataTypes"
```

However, when I run the commands for migration, only "id" and "DataTypeName" columns are being created in the table ExcelColumnDataTypes. **The columns specified in the base class are not being created.**

The contents of the **auto-generated** migration file is given below

```
class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    initial = True

    dependencies = [
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.CreateModel(
            name='ExcelColumnDataType',
            fields=[
                ('id', models.BigAutoField(auto_created=True, primary_key=True, serialize=False, verbose_name='ID')),
                ('DataTypeName', models.CharField(max_length=100)),
            ],
            options={
                'db_table': 'ExcelColumnDataTypes',
                'abstract': False,
            },
        ),
    ]
```

I have also tried removing all tables in the SQLite database file and removing the .py migration files in "migrations" folder. Even then, the same result occurs.

Can you please tell me what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

After some troubleshooting, I found out the problem.

When specifying properties in my model class, I was putting comma (,) in between two property definitions. This was causing the migration to omit such properties.

My updated model class contents are below:

```
class CustomBaseModel(models.Model):
    inserted_by = models.BigIntegerField(blank=False)
    inserted_date_time = models.DateTimeField(blank=False, auto_now_add=True)
    updated_by = models.BigIntegerField(blank=False)
    updated_date_time = models.DateTimeField(blank=False, auto_now_add=True)
    class Meta:
        abstract = True


class ExcelColumnDataType(CustomBaseModel):
    data_type_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=False)
    class Meta(CustomBaseModel.Meta):
        db_table = "ExcelColumnDataTypes"
```

Now the migration is working fine.